# How to fix an "each" loop that doesn't work

Tags: ruby, hash, each

I have a file:

```
{
  "total": 0,
  "subtotal": 807,
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 1000,
  "search": "hostname",
  "sort": {
    "by": null,
    "order": null
  },
  "results": {
    "aaa-test01.myname.com":{
      "hostname":"aaa-test01",
      "networking":"{\"hostname\"=>\"aaa-test01\", \"mtu\"=>1500, \"netmask\"=>\"255.255.255.224\", \"primary\"=>\"eth0\"}"
      }, 
    "osilek":{
      "networking":"{\"hostname\"=>\"osilek.myname.com\", \"mtu\"=>1500, \"netmask\"=>\"255.255.255.128\", \"netmask6\"=>\"ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::\",\"primary\"=>\"eth1\"}"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to have a hash like this:

```
g = {"aaa_test01.myname.com"=> "aaa-test01", "osilek.myname.com" => "osilek"}
```

The keys in this hash must be the same as the keys in results, values must be the same as the values of hostname from the results.

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

data = JSON.load File.new("any.txt")
results = data["results"]

results.each do |key, hash|
         hash.select! {|k,v| k == "networking"}
end
results.each do |key, h|
    h.each do |key, hash|
        #puts hash.select! {|k,v| k == "hostname"}
        hash = JSON.parse hash.gsub('=>', ':')
        hash.select! {|k,v| k == "hostname"}
        new_h = h.inject({}) {|new_h, (k,v)| new_h.merge(key => hash.values)}
        puts g = results.inject({}) {|g, (key, new_h)| g.merge(key => new_h.values)}
    end
end
```

In

```
new_h = h.inject({}) {|new_h, (k,v)| new_h.merge(key => hash.values)}
```

everything looks ok, and I get

```
new_h = {{"networking"=>["aaa-test01"]}, {"networking"=>["osilek"]}}
```

But in the next step instead of the `g` hash I get the `results` hash before entering the loop. The loop doesn't work well and I don't know why.

Comment: Your `new_h = = h.inject({}) ...` is unused variable.

Comment: Ok, so how to fix it?

Comment: I am just working in it. Are you sure it should be `"osilek.myname.com" => "osilek"` not `"osilek" => "osilek.myname.com"`? Because of `"aaa_test01.myname.com"=> "aaa-test01"`

Comment: If You mean the g hash it does't matter in fact. I want to use these variables to update data on server, it doesn't matter if I use the value or key first.

Comment: I can assure you that `each` itself most certainly does work.  It's your code that has a bug or two.

Comment: Did you generate the file you're trying to parse? Wherever it comes from it's not done well. It should be entirely JSON not a mix of stringified Ruby hashes and JSON.

Comment: the Tin Man, the file is an output of curl command, used to get data from theForeman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where the problem is in your code, but you can do it like this:

any.txt:

```
{
  "total": 0,
  "subtotal": 807,
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 1000,
  "search": "hostname",
  "sort": {
    "by": null,
    "order": null
  },
  "results": {"aaa-test01.myname.com":{"hostname":"aaa-test01","networking":"{\"hostname\"=>\"aaa-test01\", \"mtu\"=>1500, \"netmask\"=>\"255.255.255.224\", \"primary\"=>\"eth0\"}"}, "osilek":{"networking":"{\"hostname\"=>\"osilek.myname.com\", \"mtu\"=>1500, \"netmask\"=>\"255.255.255.128\", \"netmask6\"=>\"ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::\",\"primary\"=>\"eth1\"}"}}
 }
```

process.rb:

```
require 'json'

json = JSON.load(File.new("any.txt"))

export = json['results'].each_with_object({}) do |(k, h), exp|
  next unless h['networking']
  network = JSON.parse(h['networking'].gsub('=>', ':'))
  exp[k] = network['hostname'] unless network['hostname'].to_s.strip.empty?
end

p export
# {"aaa-test01.myname.com"=>"aaa-test01", "osilek"=>"osilek.myname.com"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
data['results'].inject({}) do |hash, (k, v)|
  fallback = JSON.parse(v['networking'].gsub('=>', ':'))['hostname']
  hash.merge("#{k}": v['hostname'] || fallback)
end

# {:"aaa-test01.myname.com"=>"aaa-test01", :osilek=>"osilek.myname.com"}
```